# non-public classes: NSCalendarDate, NSTask

Tags: ios, ios6, nstimer

When i upload to app store, i have this problems

```
non-public classes:  NSCalendarDate, NSTask
```

But i only use `NSTimer` to make my own stopwatch

This i my source code

```
self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1
                                               target:self
                                             selector:@selector(stopWatch)
                                             userInfo:nil
                                              repeats:YES] ;
```

My "Pause" method

```
pauseStart = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0];
previousFireDate = [self.timer fireDate];
[self.timer setFireDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
```

My "Resume" method

```
float pauseTime = -1*[pauseStart timeIntervalSinceNow];
[self.timer setFireDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:pauseTime sinceDate:previousFireDate]];
```

i also have  NSTimer in my AppDelegate

```
    AppDelegate* appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
appDelegate.delayTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1
                                                          target:self
                                                        selector:@selector(stopWatch)
                                                        userInfo:nil
                                                          repeats:YES];
```

I run in ios6

Could you please show me the root cause?

Thanks you so much

Comment: May be some of 3rd party libraries you have in your project use those private APIs?

Comment: @Vladimir : i try to find NSTask, NSCalendarDate in my project, but i find nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must to remove mogenerator (https://github.com/rentzsch/mogenerator) library to resolve this problems

I don't know why this project use those private APIs

Comment: It's not supposed to be in your target